# Unexpected key in jQuery AJAX POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this call:

```
bindAutoComplete('pro_title');
```

which uses this function to make an jQuery AJAX call:

```
function bindAutoComplete(id) {
    $("#" + id).keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.length > 1) {
            $.post("/ajax/autocomplete" , {id: this.value }, function(data) {
               // do stuff here...
            });
        }
    });
}
```

which works with this PHP script:

```
public function autocompleteAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        echo print_r($this->getRequest()->getPost());
    }
}
```

When I run these scripts, PHP echoes:

```
Array ([id] => test) 1
```

where 'test' in this case is the value in `this.value` from the AJAX call.

What I am looking for is `[id]` to be replaced with `pro_title`.

Please help!

Comment: what do you mean?? just replace `{id: this.value}` with `{pro_titile: this.value}`

Comment: Why do you have `echo print_r(`?  You don't need the `print_r` here, it's pointless.

Comment: @Rocket because I was testing. The print_r isn't in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The {id: this.value } should be {id: **id** }..

```
function bindAutoComplete(id) {
    $("#" + id).keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.length > 1) {
            $.post("/ajax/autocomplete" , {id: id }, function(data) {
               // do stuff here...
            });
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to send the value as well you can do {id: id, value: this.value }

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
function bindAutoComplete(id) {
    $("#" + id).keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.length > 1) {
            $.post("/ajax/autocomplete" , {id: id }, function(data) {
                // do stuff here...
            });
        }
    });
}
```